# JSX syntax error on PHPStorm

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, phpstorm, reactjs

I'm trying to conditionally set a property on a collection of elements.

```
render: {
   var buttons = [];
   for (var i = 1; i <= this.props.totalWeeks; i++) {
      buttons.push(
         <button 
            onClick={ this.changeWeek.bind(this, i) } 
            disabled={ i === this.state.currWeek }>{ i }
         </button>);
   }
}
```

Everything works great in the browser. But PHPStorm (version 8.0.3) marks the expression `{ i === this.state.currWeek }` as an error for **wrong attribute value**.

I've tried changing that with a function call, a variable, etc., but can't seem to make error go away. I've also tried to turn off that inspection rule on PHPStorm, but can't find the one setting that would turn that off.

**QUESTION**

How can I make that error go away in PHPStorm? If that's a bug, then how can I get rid of that by conditionally adding HTML attributes to a group of elements some other way?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in PHPStorm.

Comment: Indeed, my friend...

Comment: Have you tried it in v9 EAP build?

Comment: @LazyOne I have not. I was hoping to solve this without having to upgrade the entire IDE...

Comment: At least you will know that it's working there... (seems to be)

Comment: works fine for me in 8.0.3 if javascript language version is set to 'JSX harmony'. Please try invalidating caches (File/Invalidate caches, Restart) - does the problem persist? If yes, I'd suggest creating a support ticket, attaching the self-containing code snippet/file that shows up the issue

Comment: Interesting. I had my JavaScript version set to Ecma 5.1. I changed it to JSX Harmony for both the project settings and default settings. Invalidated caches and restarted. Project then took a while to index. Still showing it as an error... Now, the script tag is inside a PHP file, so maybe that has something to do with it. I created a separate .jsx file with the same component, and the error went away. Thanks for your help

Comment: PhpStorm 2016.2 still has this issue (e.g. <Text selectable={false}/> is marked as 'wrong attribute value')

Answer (score 0):

1) If it's render of react (not your custom function), it should be "render() { return ; }" against your code

It's 100% syntax error, browser ignores it, because it should, if you use it in class definition body, syntax is next:

```
class Test {
    objectExample: { some: "value" }
    functionExample() { return someExecutionCode(); }
    lambdaFunctionExample = () => { return someExecutionCode(); }
}
```

But you mix 1st and 2nd lines in same time, start as object definition, with body as a function, which are not fits to each other.

2) Your render function NOT return anything, it's making array, but not return it.